# How to delete a function or variable from the lisp image?

Tags: common-lisp, symbols, sbcl

I have a function called `read-csv` that I created.

I started using the package `cl-csv` that also has this function.

After renaming my function, I notice that `read-csv` is still part of my image.

```
(do-symbols (sym :my-package)
         (print sym)) ;; => includes read-csv
```

The same is true with variables.

If I define this:

```lisp
(defparameter hi "Buongiorno")

;;change my mind and recompile
(defparameter hi-there "Buongiorno")


> hi
"Buongiorno"  ;;<---- still exists

> hi-there
"Buongiorno"
```

How do I completely remove a symbol, variable or function from my lisp image?

Comment: + [Is it possible in Lisp to undefine Macros and Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028969/is-it-possible-in-lisp-to-undefine-macros-and-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

([makunbound](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_makunb.htm) 'hi)

([fmakunbound](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fmakun.htm#fmakunbound) 'read-csv)